# How to set a horizontal padding in percentages on floated elements?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have this menu with a number of items in it:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

The items should appear next to each other which can easily be achieved in CSS like this:

```
li {
  float: left;
}
```

Now the problem is that I want the items' horizontal padding to adjust when the browser window gets changed ("Responsive Design"). So I tried this:

```
li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 5%; /* does NOT work */
  padding: 0 10px; /* does work */
}
```

However, this doesn't work. When I use percentages, no padding gets applied to the list items at all!

How can I get this to work?

The parent element is correctly set as well:

```
ul {
  width: 960px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for any help...

Comment: it seems to work just fine in Chrome - http://jsfiddle.net/tLyxP/ what browser are you using?

Comment: Also works in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: did you try using display inline-block instead of float left

Comment: OK, solved it. Actually I had `a` elements wrapped in those `li` elements as well and had the padding applied to those. So the code I posted above *does* actually work, I just wasn't aware of it :-) Zoltan's gist really opened my eyes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use jquery to manipulate the padding of the `<li>` elements.
Also give them a class by which you will select them.

maybe try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/infoman/tUKPf/

**jQuery code**

```
/* just a show case */
$('.dyn').live('click', function() {
   var w = $(window).width(),
   paddingRight = w / 100 * 5; 
   $('.dyn').css('padding-right', paddingRight);
});


/* use this to fire the css changes on window reload */
/*
$(window).resize(function() {
   var w = $(window).width(),
   paddingRight = w / 100 * 5; //
   $('.dyn').css('padding-right', paddingRight);
});
*/
```

**html code**

```
<ul>
  <li class="dyn">Item 1</li>
  <li class="dyn">Item 2</li>
  <li class="dyn">Item 3</li>
</ul>​
```

**CSS code**

```
ul {
  width: 960px;
}


li {
  float: left;
}

​
```

​

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't really fancy a jQuery solution for something this simple though.